# How to dynamically add preferences into preferences screen and bind their values?

Tags: android, preferences

I'm new in Android.
In my app i want to do something like this: 
I have a container and i want to add item dynamically to it, in one item there may be some fields, so tree would be like this:

```
main container

- item 1
   --field 1
   --field 2
   ...
   --field n
 - item 2
   --field 1
   --filed 2
.......
 - item n
   --field 1
   --field 2
   ...
   field n
```

I want to do this using preferences, cause i need store user's info in app, but don't know how. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 31):

You need to create an xml file with an empty `PreferenceScreen`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Then in your `PreferenceFragment`you must call the following method in your `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {...}`

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_empty);
```

Afterwards you can add `Preference`s like this:

```
PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen = this.getPreferenceScreen();

// create preferences manually
PreferenceCategory preferenceCategory = new PreferenceCategory(preferenceScreen.getContext());
preferenceCategory.setTitle("yourTitle");
// do anything you want with the preferencecategory here
preferenceScreen.addPreference(preferenceCategory);

Preference preference = new Preference(preferenceScreen.getContext());
preference.setTitle("yourTitle");
// do anything you want with the preferencey here
preferenceCategory.addPreference(preference);
```

Of course you can add preferences and categories in a loop to add them dynamically.

Comment: Important to add any preference category to the preference screen *before* adding any preferences to the category, or you will get a null pointer